# Could not resolve host: dl.winehq.org

Tags: software-installation, updates, wine

I tried to install wine version 2.0.1 by following the steps listed on https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu. As I executed `sudo apt-get update` in the terminal it returned as

```
 ~$ sudo apt-get update
 Hit:1 http://repo.steampowered.com/steam precise InRelease                       
 Hit:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease         
 Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [102 kB]
 Err:4 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu xenial InRelease                
  Could not resolve host: dl.winehq.org
 Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease [102 kB]     
 Hit:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/y-ppa-manager/ubuntu xenial InRelease
 Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [102 kB]      
 Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [298 kB]
 Get:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [193 kB]
 Get:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [160 kB]
 Err:11 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                  
Temporary failure resolving 'dl.google.com'
 Get:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [195 kB]
 Get:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [2,520 B]
 Get:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [3,324 B]
 Get:15 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [3,980 B]
 Get:16 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [54.6 kB]
 Get:17 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [50.7 kB]
 Get:18 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [32.2 kB]
 Get:19 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [37.0 kB]
 Fetched 1,337 kB in 1min 16s (17.4 kB/s)                                       

 Reading package lists... Done
 N: Ignoring file '20auto-upgrades.ucf-old' in directory '/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
 W: Failed to fetch https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease  Could not resolve host: dl.winehq.org
 W: Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'dl.google.com'
 W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Now there is a term in the 4th entry that states that `Could not resolve host: dl.winehq.org` which may be related to the repository of Wine. I am now concerned that this may affect the installation process of Wine. What should I do?

Comment: Please include the output of `ping dl.winehq.org`

Comment: Here's the output of that
         ping dl.winehq.org
    PING k.global-ssl.fastly.net (151.101.8.69) 56(84) bytes of data.
    64 bytes from 151.101.8.69: icmp_seq=1 ttl=56 time=96.4 ms
    64 bytes from 151.101.8.69: icmp_seq=2 ttl=56 time=281 ms
    64 bytes from 151.101.8.69: icmp_seq=3 ttl=56 time=251 ms
    64 bytes from 151.101.8.69: icmp_seq=4 ttl=56 time=276 ms
    64 bytes from 151.101.8.69: icmp_seq=5 ttl=56 time=242 ms
    64 bytes from 151.101.8.69: icmp_seq=6 ttl=56 time=299 ms
    64 bytes from 151.101.8.69: icmp_seq=7 ttl=56 time=46.7 ms

Comment: I've searched through the internet and found that it was a problem with my connection downloading repositories. The mirror that I have been into cannot access wine and google. Clicking the "Select Best Server" in the list of servers doesn't seem to help me. Any other ideas?

Comment: Can I just download the .deb package of wine then install it to my computer manually?

Answer (score 2):

I solved it by changing to my nearest mirror server (Philippines).

It didn't download the Chrome repositories but it downloaded the Wine so I did

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends winehq-staging
```

For the first time it failed at 97% because of some missing packages but I just repeated my command then it installed Wine.

Hope it helps to whoever needs it.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem just add the package: apt-transport-https

```
sudo apt install apt-transport-https
```